# 301 redirect: does Google automatically update its index to the new URL?

Tags: google-search, 301-redirect, google-index

If I do a site wide 301 redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, will Google update its index with the new URLs?

Comment: I think you will need to submit sitemap again to google web master.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, BUT

- Ensure you don't have a 301 redirect chain like: `http://olddomain.com/test` => `http://www.olddomain.com/test` => `http://intermediatedomain.com/test` => `https://www.newdomain.com`

Once I had a 301 redirect chain only for some pages, and guess what? Those pages had "difficulties" to get updated in Google.

Also, Matt Cutts from Google said you should not have redirect chains.

The best example of a switch from HTTP to HTTPS, that's facebook. Look at facebook search results in Google. they are all HTTPS.